# Issue with SQL Output

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm confused on why this is happening. So if I leave `or opn = '9111'` in the query it will display all devices but the `IN_USE` column value will be incorrect.

If I add `AND opn = '9111'` to replace `or opn = '9111'` it will only display DXE/RESMETAL with the correct `IN_USE` value of 25.

`or opn = '9111'` OUTPUT Image:

[image]

`AND opn = '9111'`OUTPUT Image:

[image]

The reason why the `or opn = '9111'` query won't work is because it combines opn 9118 value to 9111 which will be incorrect.

EXAMPLE: Device DXE/RESMETAL should be 25 but it adds opn 9118 and it came out to value 50.

How can I fix this query to where it displays like image two but it lists all the devices and not just one? Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
              device,
              Sum(in_qty) AS in_use
            FROM
              LOT_MOVE_AGE @XXX.ITG.COM
            WHERE
              facility = 'DP1DM5'
              AND device = ANY(
                SELECT
                  device
                FROM
                  dm_device_attributes @XXX.itg.com
                WHERE
                  facility = 'DP1DM5'
                  AND status = 'A'
                  AND family LIKE 'PILOT%E'
              )
              AND departure_dttm IS null
              AND latest = 'O'
              AND (
                lpt = ANY(
                  SELECT
                    lpt
                  FROM
                    pilot_lpts
                  WHERE
                    facility = 'DP1DM5'
                    AND MODULE = 'Plasma'
                    AND category = 'In Use'
                )
                AND opn = '9111' 
              )
            GROUP BY
              device
            having
              device like 'DX%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `opn` in `group by` to separate the values.

```
SELECT
              device,
              Sum(in_qty) AS in_use
            FROM
              LOT_MOVE_AGE @XXX.ITG.COM
            WHERE
              facility = 'DP1DM5'
              AND device = ANY(
                SELECT
                  device
                FROM
                  dm_device_attributes @XXX.itg.com
                WHERE
                  facility = 'DP1DM5'
                  AND status = 'A'
                  AND family LIKE 'PILOT%E'
              )
              AND departure_dttm IS null
              AND latest = 'O'
              AND (
                lpt = ANY(
                  SELECT
                    lpt
                  FROM
                    pilot_lpts
                  WHERE
                    facility = 'DP1DM5'
                    AND MODULE = 'Plasma'
                    AND category = 'In Use'
                )
              OR opn = '9111' -- Used OR
              )
          AND device like 'DX%' -- moved this condition here 
            GROUP BY
              device, opn; -- added opn in GROUP BY list
```

You can add `opn` in `select list` also so that you can get to know that `count` and `device` refers to which `opn`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @Tejash ! Thank you for the quick response. I went ahead and tried running your recommend sql query. I got a missing right parenthesis error on line `lpt = ANY(` I'm not sure what right parenthesis its missing because all the parenthesis are open/closed.

Comment: There was some random character placed at after ) .. now see my updated answer